# handle XML request using fetch API

Tags: node.js, json, xml, fetch

I am trying to post XML string instead of JSON object to `node.js` server using fetch API.

This is my code which post JSON object:

```
handleSubmit = async e => {

    e.preventDefault();
    var request = JSON.stringify({
        drug: this.state.drug,
        disease: this.state.disease,
        type: this.state.type    
    });
    var xmlRequest = js2xmlparser.parse("request", request);

    const response = await fetch('/api/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: request
    });

    const body = await response.text();

    this.setState({
        responseToPost: body
    });
}
```

How to edit the code to post XML string(xmlRequest) instead of JSON (request).